# Swift get Image from API

Tags: swift, image, api

I need to write a function which return image (Content-Type: image) from "GET" request. I tried to use

```
let data:Data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
```

It works, but server return code is not 200. So I tried to use code below, response code is 200, but I can't visualise that image on View.

```
func getPromoImage(a:String) -> UIImage
{ var b = UIImage()
    guard let url = URL(string: a) else{return  UIImage()
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let header = ["Content-Type":"application/json",
                  "X-API-KEY":"xxxxxxxx","User-Agent":"xxxxxxxxx"]
    
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = header
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    session.dataTask(with: request){(data,response,error) in
     if let response = response {
         print (response)
     } 
        guard let data = data else {return} 
        do{
            b = UIImage(data:data) ?? UIImage()  
        }
        catch{    
        }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Comment: Samo, samo...  Asynchronous...